# How to show that for $a \in (0,\frac{\pi}{4})$, $\int^{a}_{0} \tan^n (x)dx$ tends to $0$ when $n$ tends to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose you have $a \in (0,\frac{\pi}{4})$ $$ \int^{a}_{0} \tan^n (x)dx$$ I need to show that $$\int^{a}_{0} \tan^n (x)dx \underset{n \infty}{\rightarrow}0 $$

I have a feeling I should major $tan$ by something smaller than $1$, because $\tan (x) <1$ $\forall x \in (0,\frac{\pi}{4})$, and then integrate. But I don't know how I should major it. Can someone help me? Or show me another method?

Comment: Your reasoning does not work because $\tan(x) > 1$ for $\pi/4 < x < \pi/2$. Or is the condition on $a$ wrong?

Comment: @MartinR , yes, I made an error. I will fix this.

Comment: Then $ 0 \le \int^{a}_{0} \tan^n (x)dx \le a \cdot \tan^n(a) \to 0$

Comment: @MartinR How do you get this inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a \in (0,\frac{\pi}{4})$ then
$\tan$ is monotonically increasing on $[0, a]$,
and $0 < \tan(a) < 1$, therefore
$$
 0 \le \int^{a}_{0} \tan^n (x) \, dx
 \le \int^{a}_{0} \tan^n (a) \, dx 
 = a \cdot \tan^n(a) \to 0 
$$
for $n\to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Even if $a=\frac{\pi}{4}$
$$ 0\leq \int_{0}^{a}\tan^n(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{\arctan(a)}\frac{z^n}{1+z^2}\,dz\leq \int_{0}^{\arctan(a)}z^n\,dz = \frac{\arctan(a)^{n+1}}{n+1}.$$